# Wordpress: After login in the backend I am getting redirected to the frontend

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have a problem login to the backend. If I enter the user and the pw in the backend, I am getting redirected to the frontend instead of the backend (dashboard). There, on the frontend, I see my login credentials like name and so on.

I am using the wp lockout plugin.

When the website was running on my local computer, it worked.
Then I installed the website on a host server and the site is now online. Everything works but just not the login.

Why I am not getting redirected to the dasbhoard backend?

Comment: If your problem is caused by wp lockout plugin, you should post this message on their support forum.

Comment: As you can see in my post below it is not the fault of the wp lockout plugin

Answer (score 0):

The Problem Was Something Was Blocking You And Redirecting You To Front-End So Just Do One Thing Go To File Manager In C panel And Select Your Directory Of Wordpress And Go To Plug-ins Folder And Check How Many Plug-ins Do You Have And Firstly Delete which You Have Said Then See Weather Its Allowing Or Not And If Yes Then Try Installing That Plug-in That Suites Your Needs (FULL BACKUP IS HIGHLY RECOMMENDED )

Comment: Thanks HarshaReddy for your information. I tried that and I deleted every plugin I had in the wp-content/plugins folder, but it wasn't a solution. Even tough I have deleted every plugin I am getting redirected to the frontend instead of the backend.

Comment: Ok No Issue Go To Config File And Check Weather any Configuration Was Incorrect and This May Help You http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-login-page-refreshing-and-redirecting-issue/